# atop: how to show all disks usage

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm using `atop` to monitor disks usage, network and other load parameters. my problem is,  atop will show only the top 3 disks.
How can i display all of them? couldn't find anything from man or any docs on the internet.

Comment: Well, I'm seeing all 4 of my disks (and the raid array they are in) in `atop`. Are you sure all of your disks are connected, I guess?

Comment: yes i'm sure. i guess you are checking not on production server. when you have lots of process, the bottom windows goes up and shrinks the upper window, that's why it shows max 3 disks

Comment: I have plenty of processes, but the process list doesn't start until the upper window is fully shown: http://i.imgur.com/869sYBI.png What version of `atop`?

Comment: i have this message at start `Number of variable resources limited to fit number of lines` Version: 1.26 - 2010/11/17 13:42:37     < gerlof.langeveld@atoptool.nl >

Comment: You must have too many things there for the number of lines. Try writing to a file (`atop 1 1 >file`) and see if  everything you want to see is in there.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `l` key to change maximum number of static lines per resource class while atop is running. So

1. run `atop`
2. press `l`
3. hit `enter` until it asks for `Maximum lines for disk statistics` (default is `5` lines max)
4. set it large enough to show all of your disks

Done.

See the man page at https://linux.die.net/man/1/atop for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Try glances CLI curses based monitoring tool instead. It shows all disks. To install glances run:

```
sudo apt-get install glances
```

Answer (score 0):

```
atop -PDSK <interval>
```

This gives machine parseable output of the following fields, per disk:
*name, number of milliseconds spent for I/O, number of reads issued, number of sectors transferred for reads, number of writes issued, and number of sectors transferred for write*

Answer (score 0):

The command `top` can display  CPU usage, Memory usage, Swap Memory, Cache Size, Buffer Size, Process PID, User, Commands